# Gravity forms - merging values

Tags: gravity, gravity-forms-plugin

Need some help with Gravity forms. I need to have a field, that is a merge of values ,that user has previously selected.

So, if a user has selected 3 different fields wth values of 1)XYY, 2)YYX,3)YYZ I do not need a sum, just a plain merge, in form of `XYY.YYX.YYZ`, or anything like that.

Could that be acomplised with some merging tags, or dynamically population?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Of course;
You should create two different forms. 
Collect data with field1-field2-field3, they can be single line text, number, date or anything. In the advanced tab of field settings, write a parameter name for each one, like field1-field2-field3.

In the second form create a single line text, in the advanced tab of field settings check "dynamically populate field" and write your parameters like field1.field2.field3.

In form1 settings->confirmations->redirect URL line, write your form2 page url where you added form2. Select "Pass field data via query string" and add your parameters like field1={fieldname:1}&field2={fieldname:2}&field3={fieldname:3}

When you submit form1, your form2->single line text field will capture the parameters as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with [Gravity Forms Populate Anything](https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-populate-anything/) by...

1. Add whatever type of field you'd like to use to capture the combined.
2. Set the Default Value to the merge tags of your 3 fields: `@{Field A:1}.@{Field B:2}.@{Field C:3}`.

[image: https://gwiz.io/2SEu61x]

That's it.

**Edit:** Updated screenshot for Gravity Forms 2.5 and updated merge tags to use the `@` to make them "live".